# Create a custom slot in C++, Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, oop, pyqt, qt5

in python we write custom slots quite easily by passing in the function to be called when a signal is generated. 
While in C++ connect function requires us to pass the address of the slot function or so i figured. How do i do that. I tried using **this** but did'nt work.

Python code::

```
 class imviu(QtGui.QWidget):
   def __init__(self):
     super(imvui,self).__init__()
     self.btn=QtGui.QPushButton('Browse')
     btn.clicked.connect(self.openimg)
   def openimg(self):
     #do something
```

C++ code::

```
class imviu: public QWidget
{
  public:
    imviu(QWidget *parent=0);
    QPushButton *btn=new QPushButton("Browse");
    void openimg(void);
};

imviu::imviu(QWidget *parent)
  :QWidget(parent)
{
  connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(openimg()));//this does'nt work:QObject::connect: No such slot QWidget::openimg()
}

void imviu::openimg()
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: Apart from not knowing how to use Qt in c++, you also don't seem to know the basics of c++ classes. I suggest you take a beginners' course.

Comment: let me know which part skipped you....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use signals and slots, you need to have the Q_OBJECT macro in your class as well as identifying which functions should be the signals and the slots. Have a look at [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) for a more in-depth explanation.

After this, you need to set up the project file so that MOC can generate the necessary code.

Your class definition should look like this:

```
class imviu: public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    imviu(QWidget *parent=0);

  public slots:
    void openimg();

  private:
    QPushButton *btn;
};
```